# Meaning of sentence variables

Tags: logic

Let p and q be 2 variables which represent the truthness of 2 sentences { It is hot , It is cold }

What p->~q mean? I don't understand please help.

Comment: If it is hot, then it is not cold?

Comment: Yes but we don't know if it is hot or cold in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't matter in order to know the meaning of the conditional proposition. It matters when you want to know its truth-value

Comment: To amplify the second comment by @JohnMedina-Diaz, there's a big difference between knowing what a statement means (which is what you asked about in the question) and knowing that this statement is true (which is the topic of the comment "Yes but we don't know ..."). For example, I know what "McCarter is 85 years old and lives in Florida" means even though I don't know whether it's true, I don't know how old you are and I don't know where you live.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems like there's maybe a bit of confusion arising from what $p$ and $q$ actually are. You say they represent the *truth* of the two statements, but it's better to think of them as just representing the statements --- $p$ represents the statement "it is hot" while $q$ represents the statement "it is cold".

You may then assign a truth value to these statements, for example if the temperature is over 30 then the truth value of $p$ is `true` or 1.

Now when you connect the statements with $\rightarrow$, you are just creating a more complex statement whose truth may be determined later. In this case, $p\rightarrow \lnot q$ simply means "if $p$ is true then $\lnot q$ is true", or, "if it is hot, then it is not cold".